# How is data supposed to be retrieved in ASP NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP NET Core MVC Project (using entity framework and Identity if that makes a difference in this answer) and I am a bit confused between everything I am reading on different sites. Some say that business logic is supposed to be in the model but then others show a databasecontext.cs being created and the business logic being in there. It makes sense to me to have it in the model but my problem now is that the database is set up in startup.cs services, so right now options are being sent in from services and I can't really create a new connection for every method call.

For reference:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>( options =>
{
     options.UseSqlServer(
          Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
          b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DatabaseContext).Assembly.FullName)
     );
});
```

Model - User.cs

```
namespace SPPP.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Full Name Required")]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Role Required")]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status Required")]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public IList<User_Group> User_group { get; set; }

        public User()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

DatabaseContext.cs

```
namespace SPPP.Data
{
    public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext
    {

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User_Group> User_groups { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reference anywhere to how I can set it up so that the business logic happens in the Model?

Comment: "Some say that business logic is supposed to be in the model but then others show a databasecontext.cs being created and the business logic being in there"...that's because people have different opinions about how to structure their applications, and also different approaches may be appropriate in different circumstances. All architecture / design decisions are trade-offs of one sort or another. You simply have to examine the pros and cons of each situation, decide what you think is best in the current situation (and whether it fits with your broader approach, perhaps), and go for it.

Comment: "I can't really create a new connection for every method call."...are you seeing you need to connect to more than one database in your application? Otherwise I can't see why that would matter. Creating connections should almost certainly be the concern of your database layer, not the business logic - on that at least I have a pretty strong opinion.

Comment: I am new to frameworks, so maybe this would help clarify most of my confusion. Would I pass in the DatabaseContext into the different model constructors instead of the controller?

Comment: Potentially yes, if that's where you want to use it. the dependency injection functionality should be able to help you achieve that.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the way I will go about it is passing the databasecontext into the models, then executing the queries in the models and returning that data into the controller for the view to use.

Comment: in some popular patterns for desktop development such as MVVM, the ViewModel plays its role differently compared to ViewModel used in ASP.NET MVC. Usually in ViewModel used in desktop app, we have services injected as dependencies. In ASP.NET MVC, the ViewModel simply contains data, it is much like model but because it's bound to views, so we call it ViewModel. The services are usually not injected in there, but in the controllers and pages (for razor page). Of course you can design your ViewModel to consume services but then you have finally to inject VMs into the controllers/pages instead.

Comment: Hopeless makes a good point here - if you're planning to use (for example) your User class as the viewmodel for a view (which it looks like you might, since it has those validation attributes on it), then it might make sense to keep that as a simple data-transfer object containing only properties, and have a separate UserLogic class which consumes that object and also talks to the database and implements any intermediate logic and processing needed.

Comment: In that case, my databasecontext takes in the models already. Would I just add methods that contain the queries in the databasecontext? then from the controller just call those methods

Comment: I was looking to do something like user.GetRelatedGroups() in the controller but instead if I just use the DatabaseContext class I will do _databaseContext.GetRelatedGroups(user)

Comment: @Ruben-96 that's technically fine but I think it's not the best practice. The `DbContext` belongs to the data layer which performs the most basic data tasks (CRUD and some others). When it comes to more complicated (and business-related) tasks we should put it in a separate service (belongs to the service layer). It would scale better, note about the Single Responsibility principle. If not following that principle, everything can grow bigger and bigger and hard to maintain, integrate & reuse. Always follow the best practices even when you don't really understand them.

Comment: @Hopeless I guess what I am trying to do is look for the best practice, maybe I will pick up a couple books on it. Thank you for your time and patience with me.

Comment: @Ruben-96 you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing business logic in the model when it comes to ASP.NET MVC. Your business logic should be kept within service classes. Although you could structure it in different ways. Here is a common example:

EX:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    
    pubic UserService(DatabaseContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUsersAsync() 
    {
        // Do some business logic here


        // Get data from DB like this:
        var users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();

    }
}
```

Your controller would then inject the IUserService within the constructor. You can then call any method from your service class within your controllers.

Don't forget to register your service in the startup.cs ConfigureServices() method.

You could also separate the logic to get data within a separate class like a DataAccess layer if you dont want to mix business logic with getting data from the dbcontext in the same place. Some people like to use a repository pattern as well which is ok but there is no need since EF by default already implements a repository pattern internally.